# Parsing string with KB/MB/GB etc into numeric value

Tags: python, string

In order not to invent bicycle I wonder if there is any library that is able to parse various representations of size string (MB,KB,TB,MiB,KiB,etc..) into numeric byte based value.

Comment: It's too trivial to write a library for such matter. Use switch case for prefix "MB","MiB";"KB","KiB" etc and multiply by corresponding amount.

Answer (score 7):

ActiveState Receipes has an example [here](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/578019-bytes-to-human-human-to-bytes-converter/) , though this is just a snippet, and not a library as such.

The reason it isn't a library is due to the triviality of the task which user1227804 mentions in their comment.