# Parse human-readable filesizes into bytes

Tags: python

```
example_strings = ["10.43 KB", "11 GB", "343.1 MB"]
```

I want to convert all this strings into bytes. So far I came up with this:

```
def parseSize(size):
    if size.endswith(" B"):
        size = int(size.rstrip(" B"))
    elif size.endswith(" KB"):
        size = float(size.rstrip(" KB")) * 1000
    elif size.endswith(" MB"):
        size = float(size.rstrip(" MB")) * 1000000
    elif size.endswith(" GB"):
        size = float(size.rstrip(" GB")) * 10000000000
    elif size.endswith(" TB"):
        size = float(size.rstrip(" TB")) * 10000000000000
    return int(size)
```

But I don't like it and also I don't think it works. I could find only modules that do the opposite thing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing string with KB/MB/GB etc into numeric value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9555118/parsing-string-with-kb-mb-gb-etc-into-numeric-value)

Comment: when you say bytes , is it just encoding or converting to binary (01010 ..) ?

Comment: Obviously they want the number of bytes as an int.

Comment: Why "don't you think it works"?

Comment: There is a module worth evaluating for this: https://github.com/xolox/python-humanfriendly

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here's a slightly prettier version. There's probably no module for this, just define the function inline. It's very small and readable.

```
units = {"B": 1, "KB": 10**3, "MB": 10**6, "GB": 10**9, "TB": 10**12}

# Alternative unit definitions, notably used by Windows:
# units = {"B": 1, "KB": 2**10, "MB": 2**20, "GB": 2**30, "TB": 2**40}

def parse_size(size):
    number, unit = [string.strip() for string in size.split()]
    return int(float(number)*units[unit])


example_strings = ["10.43 KB", "11 GB", "343.1 MB"]

for example_string in example_strings:
    print(parse_size(example_string))

10680
11811160064
359766426
```

(Note that different places use slightly different conventions for the definitions of KB, MB, etc -- either using powers of `10**3 = 1000` or powers of `2**10 = 1024`. If your context is Windows, you will want to use the latter. If your context is Mac OS, you will want to use the former.)

Comment: Curious not to use `1024` as the multiplier here and in the question itself.

Comment: @mlissner Not really, as K means 1000 and a KB is technically 1000 bytes (and so on for the other prefixes). 1024 is often used instead in practice, but technically that would be a KiB, a Kibibyte.

Comment: I suppose. Still, if any system said something was 5kb, I'd assume it meant kibibyte. Anyway, hopefully this discussion helps somebody someday. That was all I was really after!

Comment: I'm primarily looking to sort the damn things in a meaningful way and this works for that :)

Comment: Let's not confuse/mislead others and stick with 2^n bit depth (1024 for KB, etc). Most devs don't know the difference between kibi/kilo, mega/medi, etc.

Comment: Nobody's trying to "mislead others". Different conventions are used in different places. People who only use Windows may mistakenly think that powers of 2 is the only correct way. It's not, it's just what they are familiar with. Mac OS for example uses powers of 10. Because this is technically correct, because it's generally the definition specified by standards organisations, because it's the definition used in the question, and because no other good reason has been provided, my answer uses powers of 10.

Comment: [This answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42865724/parse-human-readable-filesizes-into-bytes#answer-60708339) provides the correct byte values

Comment: If you would like to parse with attached unit like "100MB", use "number, unit, _ = re.split(r"\s?([A-z]+)", size.strip())". Especially useful for argparse args!

Answer (score 20):

To answer the OPs question, there does seem to be a module for this, [humanfriendly](https://github.com/xolox/python-humanfriendly):

`pip install humanfriendly`

then,

```py
>>> import humanfriendly
>>> user_input = raw_input("Enter a readable file size: ")
Enter a readable file size: 16G
>>> num_bytes = humanfriendly.parse_size(user_input)
>>> print num_bytes
16000000000
>>> print "You entered:", humanfriendly.format_size(num_bytes)
You entered: 16 GB
>>> print "You entered:", humanfriendly.format_size(num_bytes, binary=True)
You entered: 14.9 GiB
```

Answer (score 11):

I liked [Denziloe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42865957/2002471) compared to everything else that came up in google, but it

- required spaces between the number and units
- didn't handle lower case units
- assumed a `kb` was 1000 instead of 1024, etc.  (Kudos to [mlissner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/64911/mlissner) for trying to point that out years ago.  Maybe our assumptions are too old school, but I don't see most software catching up to the new assumptions either.)

So I tweaked it into this:

```
import re

# based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/42865957/2002471
units = {"B": 1, "KB": 2**10, "MB": 2**20, "GB": 2**30, "TB": 2**40}

def parse_size(size):
    size = size.upper()
    #print("parsing size ", size)
    if not re.match(r' ', size):
        size = re.sub(r'([KMGT]?B)', r' \1', size)
    number, unit = [string.strip() for string in size.split()]
    return int(float(number)*units[unit])

example_strings = ["1024b", "10.43 KB", "11 GB", "343.1 MB", "10.43KB", "11GB", "343.1MB", "10.43 kb", "11 gb", "343.1 mb", "10.43kb", "11gb", "343.1mb"]

for example_string in example_strings:
        print(example_string, parse_size(example_string))
```

which we can verify by checking the output:

```
$ python humansize.py 
('1024b', 1024)
('10.43 KB', 10680)
('11 GB', 11811160064)
('343.1 MB', 359766425)
('10.43KB', 10680)
('11GB', 11811160064)
('343.1MB', 359766425)
('10.43 kb', 10680)
('11 gb', 11811160064)
('343.1 mb', 359766425)
('10.43kb', 10680)
('11gb', 11811160064)
('343.1mb', 359766425)
```

Comment:  for using `2^n` bit depth.

Comment: Well, actually, a KB **is** 1000, not 1024.
You are probably confusing it with a KiB.
The reason why 1024 was used is because of how trivial it is for a computer to convert between units when using a multiplier that is an exponent of 2.
Just shift the bits 10 bits to the left or the right, and you've converted between two adjacent prefixes.

Comment: KiB is a recent creation.  For decades KB was 1024.  Now there's differing opinions.  I'm old school.  The regex is not hard to adapt to suit your feelings on this.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [chicks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60708339/243099) answer, only use regular expression to parse the size and accept the size in integer.

```py
UNITS = {None: 1, "B": 1, "KB": 2 ** 10, "MB": 2 ** 20, "GB": 2 ** 30, "TB": 2 ** 40}


def parse_human_size(size):
    """
    >>> examples = [12345, "123214", "1024b", "10.43 KB", "11 GB", "343.1 MB", "10.43KB", "11GB", "343.1MB", "10.43 kb"]
    >>> for s in examples:
        print('[', s, ']', parse_human_size(s))
    """
    if isinstance(size, int):
        return size
    m = re.match(r'^(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s*([KMGT]?B)?$', size.upper())
    if m:
        number, unit = m.groups()
        return int(float(number) * UNITS[unit])
    raise ValueError("Invalid human size")
```

Answer (score 1):

Edit: I missed [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62271043/5339916) that points out another package, [humanfriendly](https://github.com/xolox/python-humanfriendly), for solving this problem, and this package is built for this kind of thing only (as opposed to my suggestion of poaching a utility function from a package built for entirely different purposes). So +1 that answer.

I ended up here because I wanted to avoid the dependency, but for those who don't mind it, you can find a utility that suits this well in `dask.utils.parse_bytes`.

```
import dask.utils
# supports good range of human-readable units
dask.utils.parse_bytes('150Gi')
161061273600
dask.utils.parse_bytes('150GB')
150000000000
# and potential spelling variants
dask.utils.parse_bytes('150Gb')
150000000000
```

Anyway, [here is the documentation](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/api.html#dask.utils.parse_bytes) and [here is the source code](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/_modules/dask/utils.html). [Dask](https://dask.org/) is a framework for parallel computing in python, come for the fancy `utils`, stay for the concurrency :)

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
def parse_size(size):
    units = {"B": 1, "KB": 2**10, "MB": 2**20, "GB": 2**30, "TB": 2**40 ,
             "":  1, "KIB": 10**3, "MIB": 10**6, "GIB": 10**9, "TIB": 10**12}
    m = re.match(r'^([\d\.]+)\s*([a-zA-Z]{0,3})$', str(size).strip())
    number, unit = float(m.group(1)), m.group(2).upper()
    return int(number*units[unit])
```

Answer (score 0):

The code searches for the unit of measure that contains the string. once found. with another regular expression, extract the number. once done these two things. calculate the value to bytes. if the value is not specified, it tries to treat it as Bytes but the function returns 0 if not possible conversion.

```
def calculate(data):

    convertion={"G":1073741824,"M":1048576,"K":1024,"B":1}
    result=re.findall(r'G|M|K|B',data,re.IGNORECASE)
    if len(result)>=1:
        number=re.findall(r'[-+]?\d*\.\d+|\d+', data)
        number=float(number[0])
        return int(number*convertion[result[0].upper()])
    else:
      number=re.findall(r'[-+]?\d*\.\d+|\d+', data)
      if len(number)>=1:
        number=float(number[0])
        return int(number*convertion["B"])
      else:
          return 0
```

Comment: Can you edit this answer and explain what the code does..?