# how to convert string money to integer in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe having column name "money" which is in string format and i want to convert it into integer

```
Money
"32M"
"22B"
"200k"
"3.2M"
```

** Expected Output**

```
Money
32000000
2200000000
200000
32000000
```

Comment: Write an IF statement that converts letter to multiplier.

Comment: Check that [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42865724/python-parse-human-readable-filesizes-into-bytes) post.

Comment: Make sure you check the capitalization if you use the other stack overflow code (you have "k" instead of "K")