# How to sort QTreeWidget Column?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt4, qtreewidget

I have small UI where I am using QTreeWidget and it contains 4 columns ['Folder', 'FileName', 'Size', 'Owner']
Now when I click on 'Size' Column to sort, it doesn't sort in correct order of (B, Kib & Mib) as the value of 'Size' is in string it only sort first number and mix up all Byte, Kib & Mib.

Can anyone guide what is the right approach to make sorting in correct order If column contains both type int & string ?

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class TestUI(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(TestUI, self).__init__(parent=None)

        self.setGeometry(10, 10, 700, 350)
        self.setWindowTitle('Runner up !')
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

        self.tree_widget = QtGui.QTreeWidget()
        self.tree_widget.setSelectionMode(QtGui.QTreeWidget.ExtendedSelection)
        headers = ['Folder', 'Filepath', 'Size', 'Owner']
        self.tree_widget.setHeaderLabels(headers)
        self.tree_widget.setSortingEnabled(True)

        metadata = {'Desktop': [('/u/donald/Desktop/file_test.txt', '2 MiB', 'Donald'),
                                ('/u/donald/Desktop/file_test_01.txt', '20 KiB', 'Donald')]}

        for folder, folderdata in metadata:
            top_item = QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem(self.tree_widget,
                                     [folder, '', '', ''])
            for data in folderdata:
                filepath, size, owner = data[0], data[1], data[2]

                child_item = QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem(top_item, ['', filepath, size, owner])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    WIN = TestUI()
    WIN.show()
    app.exec_()
```

It looks something like this
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Qt does not know that they are file sizes but string so it compares them with those rules. So if you want a custom ordering then you will have to override the `__lt__` method of the QTreeWidgetItem. For the comparison you can make a mapping to convert the units to numbers that can be compared but to avoid that work I prefer to use a library that does it: [datasize](https://pypi.org/project/datasize/) (`python -m pip install datasize`)

```py
from datasize import DataSize

SIZE_COLUMN = 2


class TreeWidgetItem(QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem):
    def __lt__(self, other):
        column = self.treeWidget().sortColumn()
        if column == SIZE_COLUMN:
            # DataSize does not accept space between the quantity and the unit,
            # so we eliminate the spaces:
            text_with_spaces = self.text(column).replace(" ", "")
            other_text_with_spaces = other.text(column).replace(" ", "")
            return DataSize(text_with_spaces) < DataSize(other_text_with_spaces)
        return super(TreeWidgetItem, self).__lt__(other)
```

```
for filepath, size, owner in folderdata:
    child_item = TreeWidgetItem(top_item, ["", filepath, size, owner])
```

If you don't want to use datasize then you will have to implement your own converter, something like(See [Python - Parse human-readable filesizes into bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42865724/6622587) for other examples):

```py
SIZE_COLUMN = 2
SIZE_MAPPING = {"MiB": 2 ** 20, "KiB": 2 ** 10}


def converter(text):
    string_value, unit = text.split()
    return float(string_value) * SIZE_MAPPING[unit]


class TreeWidgetItem(QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem):
    def __lt__(self, other):
        column = self.treeWidget().sortColumn()
        if column == SIZE_COLUMN:
            return converter(self.text(column)) < converter(other.text(column))
        return super().__lt__(other)
```

Comment: Unfortunately my working environment is closed and I can't install datasize in it. Can you suggest other way of doing it.

Comment: Sorry If I am asking a noob question but how it will linked up. Let's say if click on UI Column 'Size' then how TreeWidgetItem class will get trigger ?

Comment: In case I was not cleared in posted question I have re-edited the code. I am bit confused as this is gonna be my first case of overriding existing method and it is making me confused can you re post your suggestion based on edited code.

Comment: @mehulJ Just add class `TreeWidgetItem` and `converter` function , also change `child_item = QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem(top_item, ['', filepath, size, owner])` to `child_item = TreeWidgetItem(top_item, ['', filepath, size, owner])`