# Can I edit a number in a specific string, within a column?

Tags: python, csv

So I am trying to edit a CSV file (using Pandas), and as a beginner with Python I am struggling to formulate how to do this.

The columns is called 'File Size', and the entries are like:
1.0 MB
2.10 MB
12 GB
1.2 GB

I want to convert it to numbers, so I can actually compare and filter on actual size. Does anyone have an idea how to do this?

I have googled, but not actually tried typing anything out, as I am completely unaware how to do this.
I am looking for courses, so if you have any, please let me know!

Comment: Hint: if 1 MB = 1000000bytes, then 2.1 MB = 2.1 * 1000000
Find the numerical part and multiply it by the alpha equivalence part

Comment: It's not a perfect duplicate, but this should give you the general idea, then all you need to do is to apply it to the column. [Parse human-readable filesizes into bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42865724/parse-human-readable-filesizes-into-bytes)

Answer (score 1):

Here's your solution. I tested this with an example `csv` file which looks like this below:

```
sizes_in_string
1.0 MB
2.10 MB
12 GB
1.2 GB
1.232 GB
2 KB
2.1 MB
```

And here's how you can convert the `sizes in string` column in numbers:

```
import pandas as pd
import re 

# This method will convert the size strings into bytes as float
def convert_to_bytes(size_str):
    size_str = size_str.lower()
    units = {'kb': 1024, 'mb': 1024 ** 2, 'gb': 1024 ** 3, 'tb': 1024 ** 4}
    
    for unit, multiplier in units.items():
        if unit in size_str:
            return int(float(size_str.replace(unit, '').strip()) * multiplier)
    
    return float(re.sub(r'[^\d]', '', size_str))

# Read CSV file into a DataFrame
df = pd.read_csv('sizes.csv')

# Apply size conversion to the 'size' column
df['size_in_bytes'] = df['sizes_in_string'].apply(convert_to_bytes)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
  sizes_in_string  size_in_bytes
0          1.0 MB        1048576
1         2.10 MB        2202009
2           12 GB    12884901888
3          1.2 GB     1288490188
4        1.232 GB     1322849927
5            2 KB           2048
6          2.1 MB        2202009
```